Crawlee deploy on GCP return BrowserLaunchError
I'm trying to deploy a very basic crawlee application, served by an Express server. Following this example - https://crawlee.dev/docs/deployment/gcp-browsers, using PlaywrightCrawler, persistStorage is false.
The app gets deployed correctly, but when I call the crawl endpoint it returns an error right after printing [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Starting the crawler.
 "error": {
        "name": "BrowserLaunchError"
    }

This is my app.yaml
runtime: nodejs20

instance_class: B4_1G

env_variables:
  API_PORT: 8080

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 5m

I have not worked with GCP a lot, so it's possible I'm missing some config here, but it seems there isn't enough memory here to run the crawler. I don't really know how to increase the memory here beyond the instance classes.
I'm using the google cloud sdk to deploy the app. Any suggestions on how I can get this to run? Is the App engine (standard env) not the platform for this?
Thanks

Per your linked documentation, Crawlee needs a headless browser. As far as I know, you can't install a 'browser' on Google App Engine Standard (which is what your app.yaml file implies). GAE Standard also has a max request timeout that ranges from 1 - 10 minutes (see ref) and scraping usually takes longer.
Your linked documentation refers to deploying to Google Cloud Run (you can install all sorts of things there). You should also be able to run Crawlee on Google App Engine Flex since it gives you freedom to install stuff in  your Dockerfile.

Yeah crawlee uses a headless browser, I'm also starting to think the App Engine Standard is not ideal for this. I'll try out Google Cloud Run. thanks for suggestion.

You can run puppeteer on GAE standard.

@minou - What could be the issue here then? I have tried higher memory instance classes as well with no luck.

So I pushed up the repo to run on Cloud run, allocated 4GB memory to it. But I still get the same error. Is this because playwright install is not being run anywhere? I tried to run this as part of the build step, but I still get the exact same error.

@kvnam - It probably needs you to install a browser in your Cloud Run instance or there are issues with the browser driver. See this article from us on using headless firefox. I think it should be the same principle

@NoCommandLine - Yeah I tried to install playwright with dependencies, which includes the browsers but then it gives this error and build fails Step #0 - "Buildpack": su: must be run from a terminal - I found that others are facing this issue as well - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20129. I tried installing just chromium still no luck.
